# TestFlight React Native Expo crashes on startup

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, testflight

I'm disappointed because I work on an react native application managed with Expo. Up to here, all works fine. My releases with TestFlight works fine but today I face to a new problem. All my builds on TestFlight crashes on startup. At the beginning, I was thinking about an error from me, but when I try to reinstall my old builds (I'm sure they works because I tested it) the application face to the same bug. So, my theory is, my TestFlight release is going to fetch an Apple Server and he can't maybe.. So it crashes... DO you have an idea or do you think Apple is the problem ?

There is my crashes log, I verified it it's the same crashes on my old builds than on my last builds.

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8003334 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d5a89a9c pthread_kill + 272 (pthread.c:1582)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001930c5c10 __abort + 128 (abort.c:155)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001930c5b90 abort + 136 (abort.c:126)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019e8e9bb8 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019e8daec8 demangling_terminate_handler() + 308 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:67)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019e7e705c _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:701)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019e8e8fa0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019e8e8f2c std::terminate() + 48 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001898eb830 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:562)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001898fa9ec _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke + 96 (queue.c:1545)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001898eb81c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001898f9c70 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 884 (inline_internal.h:2557)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189c78340 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1790)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189c72218 __CFRunLoopRun + 2524 (CFRunLoop.c:3118)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189c71308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
16  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a12f4734 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000018c6ef75c -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3269)
18  UIKitCore                       0x000000018c6f4fcc UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4740)
19  ComMlDevSpiritApp               0x0000000100259e78 main + 88 (main.m:8)
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018992dcf8 start + 4
```

https://pastebin.com/JbyrRwQQ

Answer (score 0):

I have new informations about this crashes. When I open my device log I get that on all of my builds... :

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281394af0 V:|-(>=0)-[UIImageView:0x121d05150]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x11fd156f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281394b90 V:[UIImageView:0x121d05150]-(10)-[UIView:0x11fd156f0]   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281394b90 V:[UIImageView:0x121d05150]-(10)-[UIView:0x11fd156f0]   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
BackgroundSession <B601EDD8-BACA-4FF5-8715-E0ECABBACBF1> connection to background transfer daemon invalidated



Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.


Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `expo build:android` or `expo build:ios` instead of using `eas`. You can still use eas submit.